# How do I open an IndexedDB database with Dart?

Tags: dart, indexeddb

How do I open a database using IndexedDB and Dart? The API is not exactly the same as JavaScript's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new IndexedDB API uses Dart's support for Streams and Futures. Here's how you open an IndexedDB database with Dart M3 or greater:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:indexed_db';
import 'dart:async';

Future<Database> openDatabase(String dbName, String storeName, {int version:1}) {
  return window.indexedDB.open(dbName, version: version,
    onUpgradeNeeded: (e) {
      Database db = e.target.result;
      if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) {  
        db.createObjectStore(storeName);
      }
    });
}

main() {
  openDatabase('test-db', 'test-store').then((Database db) {
    // do database stuff
  });
}
```

In this code the `window.indexedDB.open` call returns a `Future<Database>`, which completes when the database is opened.

The `onUpgradeNeeded` function is run when the version of the database does not match the version specified.

Comment: Note, that this was added in revision: 18338. This was just slightly after the (current) last integrated build. That is, if you are using the stable version of the editor, you must continue using the old syntax until the next stable update, which will most likely be later today Monday, February 18th.

Comment: Does this also need 'dart:async' to handle the Future?

Comment: Hi, when i am trying to import the package dart:indexed_db it is not even showing up in the suggestion list is there something we need to configure? i have successfully created a page to load data from API it is working fine but i have to make use of indexed_db